# How to use c# class in Excel VBA?

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I have a standalone c# applications that does something specific (listens to TCP port and pronounces all strings that arrive to it via speech synthesizer). How can I make the c# class visible to a VBA program, same way other "References" are visible to it? I would appreciate short and clean example. I struggle to find one of those for some reason.

If there are some gotchas specific to c# <-> vba interaction, I would like to know about those too.

Here is a C# code. I build is as a class library with "Register for COM interop" setting.
When I add the resulting .tlb file to VBA references list, I expect to see SayCom library that has SayCom class with 2 methods, square and getCount. I do not see that. What am I missing?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    [assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]

    namespace SayCom
    {
        [CLSCompliant(true)]
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public class SayCom
        {
            int count;

            public SayCom()
            {
                count = 0;
            }

            [ComVisible(true)]
            public int square(int x)
            {
                ++count;
                return x * x;
            }

            [ComVisible(true)]
            public int getCount()
            {
                return count;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Main issue is using C# class in VBA. I mentioned sending strings in TCP/IP to provide some context. I see now how that may be confusing.

Comment: I have voted this to be re-opened as it is now pretty clear as to what you want. Quick question. Did you follow this? `Project settings | Application | Assembly Information | Make assembly COM visible (Set to ON) | Build | Register for COM interop (Set to ON)`

Comment: I did not do the part Assembly Information|Make assembly COM visible. I did it now, but still not seeing the class. I see the library SayCom, but is has nothing in it.

Comment: Sorry to reply so late but I just woke up :p I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    [Guid("BBF87E31-77E2-46B6-8093-1689A144BFC6")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface MyMiniSubs
    {
        int square(int x);
        int getCount();
    }

    [Guid("BBF87E31-77E2-46B6-8093-1689A144BFC7")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class Class1 : MyMiniSubs
    {

        int count;

        public Class1()
            {
                count = 0;
            }

            [ComVisible(true)]
            public int square(int x)
            {
                ++count;
                return x * x;
            }

            [ComVisible(true)]
            public int getCount()
            {
                return count;
            }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked for me too, thank you. One glitch: I had to restart visual studio as adminitrator as it was not able to update registry during build.

Answer (score 0):

The only 'gotcha', as far as I know, is that your C# code needs to be [CLS compliant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). You should be able to follow [the instructions here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dda8d7cb-0fa1-43d6-a90f-6c4bed0b40bb/how-to-use-a-c-dll-in-visual-basic-net?forum=csharpgeneral) to import your C# code as a .dll into your VB application. Disclaimer: I have not tried this myself.

EDIT: [Here's a more official MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dt232c9t.aspx) that talks about calling functions from a .dll.

Comment: I have seen some of these pages before. I am not even sure they are related to my problem. It seems like they are talking about interoperability and sharing classes between different .NET languages. What I need, is being able to interface C# .NET with non .NET VBA.

Comment: Right, so you're mainly concerned with sending strings via TCP/IP, right? I'm assuming your current application has a relatively top-level function that takes the string and transmits it. So you need to build your application as a .dll and then essentially 'import' it into your VB application. You can then look at the third link I posted in my answer to help you understand how to call your top-level function from the .dll and pass the appropriate string.

Comment: right, my question is how do I make a C# class that is visible to VBA. I would prefer it as a "type library", so the method names and type names are visible through the vba IDE, but if that fails or proves too difficult, I could settle for simple DLL and calling DLL using "Import" statement of VBA. So far I have zero progress on both fronts. No matter what settings I choose or code I write in my C# project, the result is not usable from VBA.